# Dotnet core TDD dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with writing TDD (test driven development) programming. Let's say, I create simple test method:

```
public class UtilsTest {

    private IUtilsService _utilService = new UtilService();

   [Fact]
   public void OneUtilTest {
      //here is test code
   }
}
```

It's work well. After tests are written, I want to add any logic to my UtilService. For example this:

```
public class UtilService : IUtilService {
   public string UtilLogicOne(object param) {
      //util one logic...
   }
}
```

Ok, but when writing I will need inject one or more dependencies. For example:

```
 public class UtilService : IUtilService {

       public UtilService(IDepsOne depsOne, IDepsTwo depsTwo) {
           this.DepsOne = depsOne;
           //etc...
       }

       public string UtilLogicOne(object param) {
           var result = this.DepsOne.GetResult();
          //util one logic...
       }
    }
```

This used dependencies has of course own next injected dependencies, like data adapter and other. Now I need to fix no parametric constructor in Test, because in the first step I have no parametric constructor.

How can I use service now with injected dependencies?

```
private IUtilsService _utilService = new UtilService(); //instead the single instance I need to get service with injected dependencies.
```

Is it possible? Thank you very much, for your time.

Comment: You need to mock out all of your dependencies using a mocking framework. You then inject these mocked out dependencies into the objects you are invoking in your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest investigating the [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) nuget package for taking care of your injected dependencies. There is an excellent article [here](https://horvaticblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/basic-test-driven-development-mocks-in-c-using-moq/) that talks about how to utilize Moq with TDD.

So you probably want something like:

```
var depsOneMock = new Mock<IDepsOne>();
var depsTwoMock = new Mock<IDepsTwo>();
// Call .Setup() on your mocks here if you want to mock property values or functions

var utilService = new UtilService(depsOne.Object, depsTwo.Object);

// Continue with your test
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly I need. Thank you, very much! :-)